# How to convert edit to comment?

Tags: discussion, review

New user wants to comment on some else's post, but Stack Overflow forbids that, so makes edit.

How to convert edit to comment?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/908529

Comment: In one word: don't. [The answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153019/152859) pretty much covers it nicely, I will sum it up by "don't help users bypass the rules". If one want to comment, he/she should first get 50 points it's really not that hard to get then they can post comments all day long. :)

Comment: The question is not, "how do I convert the edit to a comment" the question should be, "what do I do when someone posts an edit as a comment".  The answer is, roll back to the previous revision, or manually remove the comment from the question.  Then, optionally, inform the person who made the edit via a comment that they shouldn't edit comments into an answer/question, they need to post them as comments when they have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't actually any way to convert a suggested edit to a comment, not even for moderators.

I would rather prefer not having such feature, as it is the wrong way to use suggested edits, and it would probably going to incentive users without the privilege of commenting everywhere to suggest an edit to see it converted in a comment.

Moderators have the possibility to convert an answer into a comment, but in no case they should convert a comment written as answer from a user that doesn't have the privilege of commenting on questions asked from other users, except in the case the post contains a link that is relevant for the question, or any of its answers.

Apart this, there also some practical issues. To convert a suggested edit into a comment (provided the suggested edit just added a sentence/paragraph at the beginning/end of the post), users should be able to flag revisions, and that is not actually implemented.
Adding code to implement this feature that would then be used in very limited cases is not something I would do. It is more probable that a user writes a comment as answer, rather than suggesting an edit to add to a post something that should be a comment.